# Set color with dark/light theme with custom name

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this code:

```
...
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      supportedLocales: L10n.all,
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
      theme: MyTheme.lightTheme,
      darkTheme: MyTheme.darkTheme,
      home: TutorialScreen(),
    );
  }
```

I have a file with all costant

```
...
class AppColors {
  //BOTH
  static const white = Color(0xffFFFFFF);
  static const greyColor = Color(0xff8f8f8f);

  //LIGHT
  static const bgColorLight = Color(0xffecf4f9);
  static const primaryColorLight  = Color(0xff0072BC);

  //DARK
  static const bgColorDark = Color(0xff1b1b1b);
  static const primaryColorDark = Color(0xfffc9152);
}
```

my goal is to set a personal const in this file and call everywhere in app.

For example:

```
Text('HELLO WORLD', style:TextStyle(color: AppColors.titleColor))
```

titleColor if is dark mode is a color else is a different color. But i need this in a centralized way, something like this:

```
if(ThemeData().dark){
  titleColor = Color(0xff8f8f8f);
}else{
  titleColor = Color(0xff050505);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have like this

```dart
if(Theme.of(context).brightness == ThemeMode.dark){
   titleColor = Color(0xff8f8f8f);
  }else{
    titleColor = Color(0xff050505);
  }
```

Also you may like flex_color_scheme.

Comment: in my constant.dart don't have a context

Comment: you can pass the context or a bool as themeMode

Comment: I want this in my constant.dart not in every single style